# get DNSnamelist from existing Windows certificate and create a new certificate - powershell

Tags: powershell

I am trying to get the DNSnamelist from my existing certificate used by SQL server and using it to create a new certificate through get-certificate powershell cmdlet.
This works fine, but the DNSnamelist does not come in the correct format, so the created certificate is a broken one

```
    $RegistryPath = 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL14.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQLServer\SuperSocketNetLib'
    $sqlthumbprint= Get-ItemPropertyValue -Path $RegistryPath -Name Certificate
    $currentsqlcert= Get-ChildItem -Recurse Cert:\LocalMachine\My |Where-Object {$_.Thumbprint -eq $sqlthumbprint} 
    $sna= $currentsqlcert|select @{name='Subject Alternative Name';expression={($_.Extensions | Where-Object {$_.Oid.FriendlyName -eq "Subject Alternative Name"}).format($true)}} | select -expand "Subject Alternative Name"  -first 1
    $subjectname = Get-ChildItem -Recurse Cert:\LocalMachine\My |Where-Object {$_.Thumbprint -eq $sqlthumbprint} | select -expand subject
    Get-Certificate -Template "SQLServer"  -SubjectName $subjectname  -DnsName $sna  -CertStoreLocation cert:\LocalMachine\My
```

current output of $sna:

```
DNS Name=abcd.ghf.com
DNS Name=pqrs.ghf.com
DNS Name=test.ghf.com
DNS Name=uat.ghf.com
```

If I can get/transform $sna output to below format as comma separated string, it should work fine.

```
abcd.ghf.com,pqrs.ghf.com,test.ghf.com,uat.ghf.com
```

I tried with -replace, remove to do some slicing dicing of my ouput, but not getting it quite right. Or is there any easy way to get the dnsnamelist Any help would be great.

This seems to give the DNSnamelist in expected format but the output is truncated, using -autosize, increasing -width does not help.

```
Get-ChildItem Cert:\LocalMachine\My\* | Where-Object {$_.Thumbprint -eq $sqlthumbprint} |fl DNSnamelist
```

Comment: The output is only truncated in the **display** because of the console-width limitations by using `Format-*` cmdlets.  Just use `-join ','` on the array like `(Get-ChildItem Cert:\LocalMachine\My\* | Where-Object {$_.Thumbprint -eq $sqlthumbprint}).DnsNameList -join ','`. To verify the result is not truncated (only on screen) save that to a file. However, ifg you plan to use that with the `New-Certificate` cmdlet, you should leave it as **array** and not create a single comma delimited string of the result.

Comment: Yes @Theo you are correct. Passing it as a string creates a broken one. I made minor changes to your suggestion to convert it as an array 

`$sna=$currentsqlcert.DnsNameList -join ' '

$sna =$sna.split(' ')`

and looks like it creates a correct certificate. I just need to validate it now. Thanks for your suggestion. Sorry I dont know how to mark your comment as answer though

Comment: You don't have to merge the array into a string with `-join ' '` and then turn that back into an array with `$sna.split(' ')`.. You can simply use `$currentsqlcert.DnsNameList` because that already is an array

Comment: @Theo I tried that earlier.. It is not working as expected. As the `$currentsqlcert.DnsNameList` gives me 2 outputs as punycode and unicode so I settled with this approach.

Comment: The ```DnsNameList``` property is of type ```List<DnsNameRepresentation>``` - see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.powershell.commands.dnsnameproperty.dnsnamelist?view=powershellsdk-1.1.0. If you want an array of strings you can use ```$sna=@($currentsqlcert.DnsNameList.Unicode)``` which will use "Member Access Enumeration" to retrieve an array containing the values of the ```Unicode``` property on each DnsNameRepresentation. The surrounding ```@(...)``` is there to force the value into an array if you've only got one name in the list...

Comment: Thanks @mclayton. Your suggestion worked and I think that is cleanest way to do it.